# Postgres create view as not a view

Tags: sql, postgresql

Maintaining code from a former employee found a piece of SQL i cannot understand:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS Not a view
```

There's no info on official documentation and I've beenseeking for information on this query but to no avail.

any hint?

Comment: I've never seen this before, will be cool to see the answer here. Just upvote this question.

Comment: Are you sure this is SQL? Can you show more of the surrounding code?

Comment: This looks like it is intentionally trying to generate an error.

Comment: This fails on sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b08e1/1

Answer (score 3):

The view was deleted.

Your script was generated by an application which uses [`pg_get_viewdef(view_oid)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html). When there is no a view with a given oid then the function returns the string `not a view`. Simple test:

```
create view my_view as select 1;

select oid 
from pg_class 
where relname = 'my_view';

  oid   
--------
 151388
(1 row)

select pg_get_viewdef(151388);

 pg_get_viewdef 
----------------
  SELECT 1;
(1 row)

drop view my_view;

select pg_get_viewdef(151388);

 pg_get_viewdef 
----------------
 Not a view
(1 row)
```

Note that it **does not mean** that `my_view` does not exist. If you recreate the view it'll have another oid. The only certain conclusion is that your script is not up-to-date (It's inconsistent with the current content of the database). As a remedy you should [dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) the schema in SQL format, e.g.

```
pg_dump --schema-only --format=plain my_database > my_database.dump
```